# Spring boot Microservices in AWS Beanstalk

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Spring boot micro services which I would like to deploy using AWS Beanstalk.
Question is how can I deploy multiple services with one bean stalk deployment?
I thought of creating a zip file with runnable jars (my microservices) along with .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml file.
However I could not find a way to add multiple files to config.yml in deploy section.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if  Multicontainer Docker configuration is an option for you.

You can create docker environments that support multiple containers per Amazon EC2 instance with multicontainer Docker platform for Elastic Beanstalk.

....

A Dockerrun.aws.json file is an Elastic Beanstalk–specific JSON file that describes how to deploy a set of Docker containers as an Elastic Beanstalk application. You can use a Dockerrun.aws.json file for a multicontainer Docker environment.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker_ecs.html

Comment: Thank you. If Docker is not an option, is there any other way to deploy with out using any container services?

Comment: I don't know of any possibility. there is something called multi war file support for tomcat? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html. however, if this works, I don't think it's a good solution. A good microservice is characterized by the fact that its process is isolated (https://12factor.net/). Docker is simple and isolates the process very nicely. The setup of a spring boot app as a multidocker environment is also simple. my recommendation is a container for your spring boot app.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you.